# Have two versions of the same directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, git, dependency-injection, dependencies

**This is a typical chicken or egg problem**

In our current codebase we are moving directives from one big project to separate repositories. Unfortunately, projects dependent on these directives will be broken for a short amount of time, because we have to perform two actions at the same time:

- remove the directive from the old repository (the old project is still a dependency because of other features);
- add a dependency to new repository;

If I add the new dependency first, I have the duplicate directive situation, and Angular will throw errors. If I remove the directive from the old repository first, the directive will be completely missing.

Is there a way to keep the situation stable trough this migration?

Comment: Can't you do the changes locally and upload them all at once when it's finished and tested???

Comment: The question is pointless without real code.

Comment: @Matheno we have a code review and build process which makes it impossible to make sure it all happens at once :)

Comment: @estus it is not a specific code problem, more a of a version-control or legacy-code management problem

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting. But it is always about specific code problem. You could add a temporary decorator that disables duplicate directive. You could move a directive to separate module and override it if needed. It's not clear what the projects look like.

Comment: @estus a decorator is exactly what I need, found the article from Ben Nadel earlier today and that seems a good way to go. Unforunately the unit tests keep failing now...